# VHDL Transition Function

Tags: vhdl, xilinx

I was tasked with creating a function "transitions" that takes as input a value of type std_logic of arbitrary length. The returned value should be an integer that records the number of transitions (0 → 1, or 1 → 0) as you scan the binary bit pattern from left to right (or right to left). For example, the value 0110010011 would return 5; the value 001 would return 1.

Below is a piece of VHDL code that you can use to test your function. Add your function to the code and simulate to check that your code is giving the correct result. Show your code and the simulation results. In your simulation, display the first 100 ns, with t2, t4, t6 and t8 all shown as either signed or unsigned decimal and data displayed as binary.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
entity test_transitions is
end test_transitions;

architecture Behavioral of test_transitions is
  signal data: std_logic_vector (7 downto 0):="01111100";
  signal t8, t6, t4, t2: integer;
begin
  tt: process
  begin
    wait for 10 ns;
    data <= data+1;
  end process tt;

  t8 <= transitions(data);
  t6 <= transitions(data(5 downto 0));
  t4 <= transitions(data(3 downto 0));
  t2 <= transitions(data(1 downto 0));

end Behavioral;
```

Here's what I coded but keep receiving multiple syntax errors when I perform the Behavioral Check Syntax Test in the Xilinx ISE Design Suite. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;

entity TransitionFunction is
end TransitionFunction;

architecture Behavioral of TransitionFunction is

  function transition(signal data: in std_logic) return integer is 
    variable count: integer;
  begin
    count:= 0;
    for i in data'range loop
      if data(i) /= data(i+1) then
        count := count + 1;
      end if;
    end loop;
    return count;
  end transition;

  signal data: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0):="01111100";
  signal t8, t6, t4, t2: integer;
begin

  tt:   process
  begin
    wait for 10 ns;
    data <= data+1;
  end process tt;

  t8 <= transitions(data);
  t6 <= transitions(data(5 downto 0)));
  t4 <= transitions(data(3 downto 0)));
  t2 <= transitions(data(1 downto 0))); 

end Behavioral;
```

Error messages:
[image]

Comment: Well, what are the error messages telling you? Or were we supposed to guess?

Comment: For one thing, check your function input parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one thing, check your function input parameters.

```
function transition(signal data: in std_logic) return integer is
```

should be

```
function transition(signal data: in std_logic_vector) return integer is
```

Then in the main body, you're trying to use a function `transitions`, which doesn't exist. It should be `transition`. Or change the name of your function.

Finally, you have too many closing parentheses in

`t6 <= transitions(data(5 downto 0)));`, etc...

Note: fixing these will clear your syntax errors. This doesn't necessarily mean that your code will do what you expect it to.

---

*edit - per comments:*

> I believe because of the (i+1)

Correct. Your vector index is based at 0 - i.e. `data(0)` is the 1<sup>st</sup> bit, and `data(data'length-1)` is your last bit.

The `range` attribute of a `std_logic_vector` gives you `(n downto 0)`. For instance:

```
SIGNAL x : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);
-- x'RANGE = (7 downto 0)
```

So, when the loop gets to the end, and `i=7`, your `data(i+1)` will *always* try to access an index which is out of bounds of the vector.

> I tried limiting the index to stop at 6 with the line "for i in 0 to 6 loop"

This isn't going to work for any of these cases:

```
  t6 <= transition(data(5 downto 0)));
  t4 <= transition(data(3 downto 0)));
  t2 <= transition(data(1 downto 0)));
```

What you want is to ensure that your loop always iterates to `data'length-2`, so that when `i=data'length-2`, `i+1 = data'length-1`, which is the last possible index of your vector.

So,

```
for i in 0 to data'length-2 loop
  if data(i) /= data(i+1) then
    count := count + 1;
  end if;
end loop;
```

Note that this will also work for 1-bit vectors:

```
t1 <= transition(data(0 downto 0));
```

In this case, the `for` loop will simply be skipped, and `count` will return with its initialized value `count := 0`, which makes sense as there will be no countable transitions.

Comment: Yeah, the code still won't run, that loop in the function is going to go out of range.

Comment: @DonFusili Correct, hence the last sentence. This just answers his question about the syntax errors. I intentionally leave working out the homework to the OP

Comment: How would you keep it from going out of range?

Comment: @SofiaZapata I can respond soon; in the meantime, do you understand why it goes out of range?

Comment: I believe because of the (i+1), I tried limiting the index to stop at 6 with the line "for i in 0 to 6 loop"... and I get no syntax errors but my simulation is not returning any values.